# How to pass additional parameters in disconnect message of aws iot mqqt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

Disconnect message has the following structure in aws iot core:

```
{
"clientId": "186b5",
"timestamp": 1573002340451,
"eventType": "disconnected",
"sessionIdentifier": "a4666d2a7d844ae4ac5d7b38c9cb7967",
"principalIdentifier": "12345678901234567890123456789012",
"clientInitiatedDisconnect": true,
"disconnectReason": "CLIENT_INITIATED_DISCONNECT",
"versionNumber": 0
```

}

Here client id has limit of 128 bytes so I am not able to pass some data, how can I pass additional attribute to get from disconnect message?

Comment: how did at first you got to the right AWS IoT Topic?
as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html#connect-disconnect,  
they state it to be:

    $aws/events/presence/disconnected/clientId

wherein clientId is ofcourse what a publisher/subscriber passes, but even on explicitly disconnecting, my subscriber doesnt seem to receive any messages for the above topic, neither for something like `aws/events/presence/disconnected/clientId`